# Inversely Proportional and Inversely Related

Tags: terminology

Suppose that we have a formula like $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$. Is it correct to say that y is inversely proportional to x? what about y is inversely related to x? If not, what other phrase should we use?

Comment: Inversely proportion always (and *only*) means $xy=\text{const}>0$, whilst inversely relation is much more widely defined: almost whenever the two factors $x,y$ counterbalance each other, say the increase of $x$ implies the decrease of $y$, we call them inversely related.

Comment: Well, you wouldn't (I wouldn't, anyway) say "$y$ is proportional to $x$" to describe the expression $y=\sqrt{x}$. Therefore, you pretty much can't say "...inversely proportional..." to describe $y=1/\sqrt{x}$.